# Formatting Pandas groupby() for merge

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I was hoping someone could help me with something relatively simple I have been trying to do. Recently, I used `groupby` to sum over different groups in my `df`, as you can see below:

```
                      MSA.name ifr.industry
0   Abilene, TX Metro Area           90
1   Abilene, TX Metro Area            P
2   Abilene, TX Metro Area           90
3   Abilene, TX Metro Area            F
4   Abilene, TX Metro Area           90
5   Abilene, TX Metro Area           90
6   Abilene, TX Metro Area           90
7   Abilene, TX Metro Area           90
```

Then I sum employees over industries with `df.groupby(['MSA.name', 'ifr.industry'])['employees'].sum()`

```
MSA.name               ifr.industry        employees  
Abilene, TX Metro Area 10-12               720
                       13-15                70
                       16                   87
                       17-18                54
                       20-21                77
                       22                  403
                       23                  324
                       24                  383
                       25                  701
                       28                  310
                       29                  198
                       30                  233
```

However, I want to merge this back into the original `df`, but I can't see how to do this easily. I wanted to know if there was a way that `groupby()` would list the `MSA.name` for every observation after I do the `groupby()`.

Comment: `df.groupby(['MSA.name', 'ifr.industry'])['employees'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @Wen Thats absolutely amazing, thanks so much!

Comment: I add another way, can save the `merge` step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this first `df.groupby(['MSA.name', 'ifr.industry'])['employees'].sum().reset_index()`

also , you do not need `merge` here, using  `transform`

```
df['sum']=df.groupby(['MSA.name', 'ifr.industry'])['employees'].transform(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this has been incredibly informative!

Comment: @danny ,Glad it help ~ have a nice day